# Find the area of the region bounded by two curves.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

Help me spot my mistake.

I keep getting -1/3, but the correct answer is 1/3. They intersect at x = 1 and x = 0

[image: Given the following]

[image: Upper fucntion - lower function]

[image]

[image: Plugging in one]

Answer (score 1):

The one that is "on top" goes first in the integral.  So you have them backwards because on the interval $[0,1]$, $x^2$ is less than the other.

EDIT: You can plug the number $x=1/2$ into both functions to determine which one is above.

Comment: Oh okay. I see!